# Multiple $GetPosts with If / Else Statement in Wordpress?

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress

I have this plugin in WordPress that I've heavily modified. The purpose of the plugin is originally to display thumbnails for whatever category you tell it to. As of right now, I've made it done much more than that. But anyways, here is the shortcode for the plugin..

```
[categorythumbnaillist 7]
```

7 being the category ID of course. The plugin gets the posts for whatever category you tell it to (ie. 7,3,4) and orders them using this code that I made:

```
$args=array(
       'showposts'=>5,
       'category'=> $listCatId[1],
       'orderby'=> $categoryThumbnailList_OrderType,
       'order'=> $categoryThumbnailList_Order

       );
      $myposts = get_posts( $args);
```

Now, I wanted the plugin to only show posts if it has has the tag "news" in it. So I did the news tag in like so:

```
$args=array(
      'tag' => 'news',
      'showposts'=>5,
      'category'=> $listCatId[1],
      'orderby'=> $categoryThumbnailList_OrderType,
      'order'=> $categoryThumbnailList_Order

       );
       $myposts = get_posts( $args);
```

This sucesfully displays 5 posts if it has the "news" tag in it. But here is the problem...

I'm going to be using this plugin multiple times on one page. So when I use the shortcode listed above with a different category ID, the plugin doesn't display posts for the respective category since there are no posts tagged with "news" other than in the news category. :(

To fix this problem and make the plugin display only news posts with the tag "news" while still displaying the other category posts properly... I've tried setting up a simple if / else statment.. like so:

```
$args=array(
      'tag' => 'news',
      'showposts'=>5,
      'category'=> $listCatId[1],
      'orderby'=> $categoryThumbnailList_OrderType,
      'order'=> $categoryThumbnailList_Order
       );

$targs=array(
  'showposts'=>5,
  'category'=> $listCatId[1],
  'orderby'=> $categoryThumbnailList_OrderType,
  'order'=> $categoryThumbnailList_Order

    );

if ( tag == true ) {
$myposts = get_posts( $args);
}

else {
$myposts = get_posts( $targs);
}
```

This sucesfully filtered the news posts to only show posts tagged with "news" in them.. but then it doesn't get posts for any other categories. :(

If anyone has any idea how I would fix this if / else statement or change the code to make the plugin display only news posts with the tag "news" while still displaying the other category posts properly, please fill me in! :)

Comment: anyone have any suggestions? :(

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong - it looks like you're missing a `$`:

```
if ( tag == true ) {
```

But I think it'd be more flexible to add another parameter to your shortcode for the tag, and if it's present, use it.  Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'showposts' => 5,
    'category'  => $listCatId[1],
    'orderby'   => $categoryThumbnailList_OrderType,
    'order'     => $categoryThumbnailList_Order
);

if ($tag) { // tag from your shortcode
    $args['tag'] = $tag;
}

$myposts = get_posts( $args);
```

You'll probably need to start naming your shortcode parameters.  Check out [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for details.

Comment: Thanks man! this deffinitly lead me in the right direction. Although I can't wrap my head around shortcode paramaters, I'll keep trying to solve this issue.